# Nginx Error When Editing Config

Tags: nginx

I have been trying to install flarum using nginx as my server but when i restart nginx i get multiple problems if anyone could figue out where i went wrong i would really appreciate it

**when i run "systemctl restart nginx" this happens**

Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

**then when i run "nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf" this happens**

nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/creativethoughts:14
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

**Heres what I have done since i last restarted nginx**

Create a new sites-available file then copied it to sites-enables using "sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/creativethoughts /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/"

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name forums.creativethoughts.us      www.forums.creativethoughts.us;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; }
location /api { try_files $uri $uri/ /api.php?$query_string; }
location /admin { try_files $uri $uri/ /admin.php?$query_string; }

location /flarum {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY ""; # Fix for https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerability
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}

location ~* \.html$ {
    expires -1;
}

location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 1M;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}

gzip on;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types application/atom+xml
           application/javascript
           application/json
           application/vnd.ms-fontobject
           application/x-font-ttf
           application/x-web-app-manifest+json
           application/xhtml+xml
           application/xml
           font/opentype
           image/svg+xml
           image/x-icon
           text/css
           text/plain
           text/xml;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
```

}

**--------------------------------------------------**

edited nginx.conf and removed the comment from "server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;"

finally tried to restart and got the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are specifying the `/` location twice.
2. You've declared the gzip directive multiple times.
3. You are not closing the server block.

Here is the fixed one:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name forums.creativethoughts.us      www.forums.creativethoughts.us;

location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; }
location /api { try_files $uri $uri/ /api.php?$query_string; }
location /admin { try_files $uri $uri/ /admin.php?$query_string; }

location /flarum {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY ""; # Fix for https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerability
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}

location ~* \.html$ {
    expires -1;
}

location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 1M;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
}
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types application/atom+xml
           application/javascript
           application/json
           application/vnd.ms-fontobject
           application/x-font-ttf
           application/x-web-app-manifest+json
           application/xhtml+xml
           application/xml
           font/opentype
           image/svg+xml
           image/x-icon
           text/css
           text/plain
           text/xml;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
```